# How to get apt to make files in /var/cache/apt/archives always world-readable?

Tags: permissions, apt, cache

I want the files in`/var/cache/apt/archives` to always have read permissions for everyone. That is, whenever `apt` downloads a new file into this directory, it should make it world-readable. This is not the case currently, an example entry from `ls -l /var/cache/apt/archives` looks like this:

```
-rw------- 1 root root 26928 2009-05-03 20:34 /var/cache/apt/archives/sl_3.03-16_amd64.deb
```

What should I do to have the files always world-readable?

(Aside: I want this because I have a few Ubuntu laptops on a LAN and using `scp` or `rsync` I occasionally copy `/var/cache/apt/archives`from one laptop to the other. I don't use apt-cacher or squid-deb-proxy etc because at any point any subset of the laptops might be connected to the network; I have no central server.)

Answer (score 1):

APT is affected by the `umask` of root which is inherited from the global setting from `/etc/profile`. You've likely a line in it with `umask 077`. To make the files world-readable by default, you'll have to change it to:

```
umask 022
```

To change default the permissions of existing files, run:

```
sudo chmod 644 /var/cache/apt/archives/*
```

To copy archives from one machine to another, you can use `netcat`. On the source machine (ip = `10.0.0.2`) which has `.deb` files to be distributed you need to install `netcat-traditional` and run:

```
cd /var/cache/apt/archives
tar c * | nc.traditional -l -p 1234
```

Replace `*` by the files you want to copy.

On the target machine, run:

```
nc 10.0.0.2 1234 | sudo tar xv -C /var/cache/apt/archives
```

Comment: Yeah that's it (memory was failing me sorry and btw don't mention reputation like that the next time it's rather condescending).

Comment: Won't changing the umask affect permissions of all files created by root? That might not be a good idea.

Thanks for the netcat idea. Although if I'm executing something on both machines, I might as well `sudo chmod og+r` on one and then `sudo rsync -av --progress --ignore-existing` on the other (which is what I normally do) so that I get the benefits of `--ignore-existing` too.

Comment: @RolandTaylor sorry for insulting you, please accept my apologies.

Comment: @prateek That would indeed affect the permissions of all files created by root. Your solution with rsync is even better, post it as answer.

Comment: @Lekensteyn it's cool :D

Comment: @Lekensteyn : Hmm, that's not quite the answer, though. The question was about the permissions being set correctly _automatically_ (I could of course manually chmod, but that needs an extra ssh to get to the correct machine), not about copying. I mentioned the copying bit only because someone might have asked "why do you want to do this?".

Comment: @prateek: if you meant setting default permissions, have a look at http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/1314/8250 Otherwise, it's straightforward to create a program in your `$PATH` that's named `apt-get` and sets the preferred `umask`.