# Installing files from archive cache

Tags: 14.04, apt, software-installation, cache, archive

How to make a backup of apt archive cache? If I make a backup of the archive cache can I install the applications in the current system to any system, which is running the same OS, using the archive files and without further download? If yes, how to do this installation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can.

To backup, just copy/paste the .deb files.

To install, either copy them back to the archives on the new system, or use the 
 `dpkg -i *.deb` command.

PS: If the two machines are on the same network, use netcat as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/77175/20054).

PSS: Another tool to use on the LAN is [apt-cache-ng](https://askubuntu.com/a/51570/20054).

Comment: will any download made using apt will create a .deb file on archive?

Comment: what about adding the repositoires in the current system to the new system?

Comment: will all the libraries in the current system be available in the new system after doing this, or i have to do something for this?

Comment: 1-Yes. 2-why? The new system has its own repositories. 3. No, the new system will have what you transfer, or install from the repositories.

Comment: 2- i mean the ppa repositories. while doing many installations i need to add some ppa lines in terminal and do update (for example gnome-shell). without the ppa repository added in the new system, can I install such softwares?

Comment: If packages are only available in PPAs, you either need to add the PPAs, or transfer the archived .deb packages from one system to another. I don't see any other ways.